# How to fix this code that opens a webbrowser?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to Python and trying to learn this wonderful language for webbscraping.

I wrote a very simple program to learn how to use the requests module and BeautifulSoup module.

This program is supposed to open the five first results of a google search in a new window. The key words of the search being written as an argument.

```
# lucky.py - Opens several Google search results.

import webbrowser, bs4, requests, sys

print('Googling...') # display text while downloading the Google page
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

# Retrieve top search result links.
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

# Open a browser tab for each result
link_elems = soup.select('.r a')
num_open = min(5, len(linkElems))
for i in range(num_open):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + link_elems[i].get('href'))
```

When I launch the program in the terminal, it displays a terminal window with the text "Googling..." but the it closes and no webbrowser windows are opened.

To resolve this problem I tried to use urllib.request with : `urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])).read()`

I also added the lxlm : `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")` because it was recommended to use it.

The program still doesn't work and I a bit confused...
I runned it on a Miscrosoft Windows OS.

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: What does `print(len(linkElems))` say?

Comment: I continued searching and the problem comes from the `soup.select('.r a') `which is an empty list... I also tried to use `soup.find_all("div,"r")` which still returned an empty list...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line -

> webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + link_elems[i].get('href'))

with these two lines of code -

> chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
>   webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open('http://google.com' +
>   link_elems[i].get('href'))

If that doesn't work, please try supplying the "new" argument to webbrowser.get like -

> webbrowser.open(url, new = 2)

Supplying new as 1 opens the webpage in a new window if possible and supplying it as 2 opens the new webpage in a new tab if possible.

Comment: I continued searching and the problem comes from the `soup.select('.r a')` which returns an empty list... I also tried to use `soup.find_all("div,"r")` which still returned an empty list... There is no problem with the webbrowser